# Object getting faster, without any reason

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a code, where a circle flows around the screen. If you click the circle, it will add a point to the score. This is working, and the circle is moving.

However, the circle is getting faster, every time it gets clicked. I don't know why this happens, because I have not implemented anything like that. Below is my code and the onClickListener.

```
        //Getting intent and checking what difficulty and setting circle color
        Intent cameFrom = getIntent();
        String difficulty = cameFrom.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.difficultyIntentExtra));
        if (difficulty.equals(getString(R.string.easy))) {
            moverSpeed = (float) 1.0;
            DrawableCompat.setTint(toMove.getDrawable(), getColor(R.color.easy));
        } else if (difficulty.equals(getString(R.string.normal))) {
            moverSpeed = (float) 6.0;
            DrawableCompat.setTint(toMove.getDrawable(), getColor(R.color.normal));
        } else if (difficulty.equals(getString(R.string.hard))) {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(toMove.getDrawable(), getColor(R.color.hard));
            moverSpeed = (float) 12.0;
        } else {
            moverSpeed = (float) 1.0;
            DrawableCompat.setTint(toMove.getDrawable(), getColor(R.color.easy));
        }

        //OnClickListener for circle add score point
        toMove.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
            scorenow++;
            String newScore = getString(R.string.score) + " " + scorenow;
            scoreTxt.setText(newScore);
        });

        //Creating the mover
        final Handler leHandleur = new Handler();
        final Runnable mover = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Get coords
                float xNow = toMove.getX();
                float yNow = toMove.getY();

                if (((yNow <= yNext + moverSpeed) && (yNow >= yNext - moverSpeed)) || ((xNow <= xNext + moverSpeed) && (xNow >= xNext - moverSpeed))) {
                    //If position arrived take new Coords
                    float[] newCoordiantes = randomGenerator(xWidth, yHeight, 0, 0);
                    xNext = newCoordiantes[0];
                    yNext = newCoordiantes[1];
                }

                if (xNow < xNext) {
                    xNow += moverSpeed;
                } else if (xNow > xNext) {
                    xNow -= moverSpeed;
                }

                if (yNow < yNext) {
                    yNow += moverSpeed;
                } else if (yNow > yNext) {
                    yNow -= moverSpeed;
                }

                toMove.setX(xNow);
                toMove.setY(yNow);


                //Handler delay
                leHandleur.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }
        };

        //Getting width and height of the layout, after it was created
        rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
            xWidth = rootLayout.getWidth() - toMove.getWidth() - moverSpeed; //Width without max width movement
            yHeight = rootLayout.getHeight() - toMove.getHeight() - moverSpeed; //Height without max height movement
            Log.d("Max_Heigth_Width", "onCreate: \nHeight: " + yHeight + "\nWidth: " + xWidth); //Log

            //Running mover
            leHandleur.post(mover);
        });
```

As you can see, there is nothing that could make the circle move faster in the onClickListener.

Comment: Are you sure that score now is not somewhere linked to moverSpeed?

Comment: I don't know the rest of the code or how do you call that handler so I will make assumptions, I think when it gets touched, the old handler is still running and changing its position, so when you add a new handler it results in two handlers moving the circle so double its speed, and every time you touch it and add a handler it doubles the distance it moves in millisecond.

Comment: if you're running the handler through a thread, you should stop the old thread first before calling a new one.

Comment: @emmanuel Conradie no it's not linked to anything except the score and that's why I'm confused.

Comment: @omar shawky so you mean I should add the onClickListener in the Runnable? Like not in the main thread, but I should put it in the "mover" runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My ViewTreeObserver always started the mover runnable as soon, as something in the view changed, what happened, when the circle was clicked. To fix it, I simply stopped the runnable, because it will be activated later, anyways:

```
leHandleur.removeCallbacks(mover);
```